# How to enable using TAB button in my Windows Form Application (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So i have a few text boxes in my Form Application, and when I press Tab, instead of moving to the next field it first jumps to the button at the bottom of the form or goes to a random location.

Is there a code i need to use or can i change the properties in the design tab?

needless to say I am very new to Visual Studio, so any detailed help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the designer, each element has a property called `TabIndex`. This sets the ordering using tab to move between controls. Set the "first" control on your form to 0. The next control to get focus when pressing tab should get a `TabIndex` of 1, the next one a 2, etc. Some controls ignore the `TabIndex` where it doesn't make sense (e.g., a `Label`). You can also specifically exclude some controls with the `TabStop` property - set it to false to exclude that control.

Container controls (e.g., `GroupBox`, `Panel`) use a nested index, so the `TabIndex` resets within the container. The first element to get focus in the container will have index 0, and so on.

Visual Studio offers a nice tool to easily set the ordering. With the designer open, click View->Tab Ordering. You then click on each element in turn, and it sets the `TabIndex` of everything for you.

Comment: Many thanks dude. is it possible for me to ask another question please? i have a question regarding DateTimePicker object..

Comment: Yup, just ask it in a separate question by clicking the "Ask Question" in the corner!

Comment: oh well i need to wait for 90 minutes :( no worries i will do so in a bit

Answer (score 0):

sorted!

on the Properties box, on the properties tab, I can change the order of boxes and items by changing TabIndex!!!

sorted!